# How do I create an ImageButton with a drawable src?

Tags: android

I have the following contents in a drawable called `gray_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <size
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp" />
    <solid android:color="#666"/>
</shape>
</selector>
```

In my app's main layout, I have the following section

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/gray_button"
        android:layout_margin="160dp"
        />
```

Unfortunately, the button displays as a small rectangle instead of an oval.
I am fairly certain I have done something stupid.

How can I make my button display the drawable properly?

---

**Update**: Based on the given answer I've switched the drawable to the following but now it just displays as a large rectangle instead of an oval.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <size
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your shape, you are using a selector with a duplicated URI, so remove the selector and use only the shape:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <size
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp" />
    <solid android:color="#666"/>
</shape>
```

With this approach you will see the rectangle because is the background button and your drawable as image.

Comment: This does improve things, but it is still showing a rectangle and not an Oval.

Comment: I tested this approach and it works fine with constraint layout, so the problem is your approach with another container. Try to use a little drawable, changing the width and height, with 300dp is so big, so the result is a rectangle because the imageButton container is little than the resource. A drawable shape is not a vectorial (Using a match parent imageButton then you can see the drawable)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove selector and margin `android:layout_margin="160dp"`

This should work:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<size
    android:width="300dp"
    android:height="300dp" />
<solid android:color="#666"/>
</shape>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/gray_button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try it on simple Button instead of ImageButton. If it still doesn't works, then probably the problem is in gray_button.xml file otherwise fine.